# Take a string and return number of words in string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am working on a problem from CoderByte. I am curious about my code. The first function `returns 6` and the second function `returns 4` which is the correct count. I am trying to understand why that is happening. As when I console log `newArr` it shows only 4 items.

Here is the problem from CoderByte: - Using the JavaScript language, have the function WordCount(str) take the str string parameter being passed and return the number of words 
the string contains (ie. "Never eat shredded wheat" would return 4). Words will be separated by single spaces.

```
var wordCount = function (str) {
    var newArr = str.split(' ');
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i += 1) {
        total += i;
    }
    return total;
};
```

///

```
wordCount('Never eat shredded wheat');

var wordCount = function (str) {
    return str.split(' ').length;
};
```

Comment: your `total` = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3  = 6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are adding i instead of one.

```
total += i;
```

Basically you have

```
iteration 1 : total = total + 0 = 0 + 0 = 0
iteration 2 : total = total + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
iteration 3 : total = total + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3
iteration 4 : total = total + 3 = 3 + 3 = 6
```

Comment: I got tired of typing